# Make a character face the opposite way (2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set up an enemy which moves for two seconds and then faces the opposite way for two seconds, etc

But, when coding this, I can't get the character walking left, it gets kinda stuck.

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour {

public int speed = 2;

void Start () 
{
}

void Update () 
{
    float auto = Time.deltaTime * speed;
    transform.Translate (auto, 0, 0);
    StartCoroutine(Animate ());
}

IEnumerator Animate()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.back);
    speed *= -1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward);
    speed *= -1;
}
}
```

[video of the problem](https://vimeo.com/197781495)

Comment: The video is great help in cases like this! Nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start a Coroutine you're starting it in a new thread, which means you're doing a new **Animate()** every time **Update()** is run, which would be around 60 times per second.

This is why it works in the beginning but then once there are 120 instances of Animate() telling the sprite to turn around all the time you get some really weird behaviours.

I think what you want is to put the **StartCoroutine(Animate());** in your Start() method and change the code in **Animate()** to make it loop until unit is dead or some other state instead.

```
void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(Animate());
}


IEnumerator Animate()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.back);
        speed *= -1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward);
        speed *= -1;
    }
}
```

and, of course, remove the "StartCoroutine(Animate ());" from Update().

Comment: Exactly what I was typing when I saw the "New answer..." popup :)

Comment: Okay, that worked, more or less. Now, the speed value changes (when called `speed *= -1`), but the character keeps walking on the same direction

Comment: In the video you displayed the character facing right, then after 2 seconds facing left (for a little while). Do you mean to say that the character is always facing right now? That sounds weird, make sure you haven't edited any other code, especially the: 

transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward);

You could try setting the rotation with hard values, I guess, which would be something like: 

transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, -100, 0, 0); 

When looking back and 100 when looking forward. But it should be the same result as your current code...

Comment: 1 * -1 = -1 

and 


-1 * -1 = 1

It's a mathematical way of toggling the value.

Comment: @Fredrik My bad, my brain is tired apparently. Deleted my comment.

Comment: It was a good comment though, took me a few seconds to realize it wasn't a mistake as well... At first glance it may seem like a copy-paste error.

Comment: Nope, @Fredrik the character only WALKS right, not left

Comment: Oh... Ok... Weird. Is the speed variable not changing? Im on bike right now, will get back to you shortly, when I'm home!

Comment: The speed var is actually changing... @Fredrik

Comment: Need some helpp :'( @Fredrik

Comment: Wait... You didnt remove the entire Update method, did you? The Update method should be like it originally was, just remove the StartCoroutine(Animate ()); from it.

Comment: The Update method is just the same, but without the StartCoroutine @Fredrik

Comment: I see, I just re-created the code locally. This is really weird, and I'm not entirely sure what's happening. The object is moving back and forth until the IEnumerator goes off the first time. You can see this if you do WaitForSeconds(10) and before 10 seconds adjust the value of speed in the editor. It will move with the speed it uses there. And the Coroutine changes that value but once the Coroutine changes the value it stops listening to it. I think perhaps that the Coroutine, which runs in a new thread, has its own instance of the code which runs. But this doesn't make sense either

Comment: because it seems to work if you set the position directly. I also tried with callbacks. So the fault is perhaps with transform.Translate... Try using a different method of moving the object..?

Comment: This is really mind-boggling for me... I'm going to leave another answer, showcasing why this is weird.

Comment: Okay, thanks. If you want to, you can just go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467459/character-not-changing-direction) and answer there @Fredrik

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh of course. Hahaha I'm so stupid. Thank you!!