# Character not changing direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a character that changes its facing (right or left) every two seconds. After that two seconds, the speed is multiplied by -1, so it changes its direction, but it just keeps going right (->)

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour {

public int speed = 2;

void Start () 
{

    StartCoroutine(Animate ());
}

void Update () 
{
    float auto = Time.deltaTime * speed;
    transform.Translate (auto, 0, 0);
}

IEnumerator Animate()
{
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.back);
        speed *= -1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward);
        speed *= -1;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `transform.Translate` translates the object in it's local space, not the world space.

When you do the following :

```
// The object will look at the opposite direction after this line
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.back);
speed *= -1;
```

You flip your object **and** you ask to go in the opposite direction. Thus, the object will translate in the initial direction afterwards.

To fix your problem, I advise you to not change the value of the `speed` variable.

Try to imagine yourself in the same situation :

1. Walk forward
2. Rotate 180° and walk backward

In the end, you "continue" your path in the same direction

Here is the final method :

```
IEnumerator Animate()
{
    WaitForSeconds delay = new WaitForSeconds(2) ;
    Quaterion backRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.back) ;
    Quaterion forwardRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward) ;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return delay;
        transform.rotation = backRotation;
        yield return delay;
        transform.rotation = forwardRotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you, this was really annoying me, couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Excuse me, but could you please write the full method? :|

Comment: just remove both `speed *= -1;` from the Animate()

Comment: Okaay so thank you very much, this problem was annoying me too, I didn't know what to do!

Comment: @Ardi : I wrote the full function with some optimizations ;)